# Why does logical_gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_logical_devices('GPU') lead to an empty list?

Tags: gpu, tensorflow2.0

I use Tensorflow version 2.0 and will like to configure the GPU's with it.

for Tensorflow 1.x, it was done in following way

```
# GPU configuration
from keras.backend.tensorflow_backend import set_session
import keras
configtf = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto() 
configtf.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
configtf.gpu_options.visible_device_list = "0"
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=configtf)
set_session(sess)
```

However, set_session is not longer available in Tensorflow 2.0, so to use access GPU's, I tried following [this guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu). Both the codes below lead to empty list of available GPUs, which means tensorflow is not using them.

```
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices("GPU")
gpus
logical_gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_logical_devices('GPU')
logical_gpus
```

I do have Tesla K80 access available.

What will be the right way to configure tf for it to use the available GPUs? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What worked during this situation was to export the available GPU's into the conda environment using following command.

(your_environment) user@machine: export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0